# How to tell if one commit depends on another commit when merging (svn)?

Tags: svn, merge, svn-merge

Say I have the following commits on the two branches:

```
(trunk) A - B - C

(produ) A
```

I want to merge the work done in C but not necessarily B.

There is a chance that the code in C never touched any of the areas changed by B (ideal).

But it could also be possible that C changed some of the same areas as B. So when I do a merge I get some of B's changes (specifically the changes C made to B's changes).

*Is there a way to detect when one commit's changes 'depends' on another commit's changes?*

I know I can examine both sets of changes and eyeball it, but surely there must be a better way.

Comment: You're using a 3-way merge tool, correct?

Comment: No I just run merge on the command line and when a conflict appears I resolve it inline with an editor. I can see how a merge tool would help a little but ideally I'd like to run a command that detects this situation for me without me having to look at the code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no such tool to cherry-pick changes to a single line automatically. I suggest using a graphical 3-way merge tool so you can manually see the changes more easily. For example, kDiff3 or Meld. I'm sure there are many others out there.

Comment: I don't even need to know on a line by line basis, just that once commit modifies the changes of another commit in general. However, getting a merge tool is a good suggestion regardless.